# Regular expressions in multi-line text code in Java

Tags: java, regex

for the following XML below I want to find the patientInfo tag and find out what is in between the < and "patientInfo>" using Java.  I think the bes way is to use a matcher.  So I wrote code as the following (assume that above String is in variable k).  I would then use m.group(0) or m.group(1).  The thought being, once I do this, I can get contained information.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<.*:patientInfo>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(k);
    System.out.println(m.matches());
```

but matches is false.  I guess I don't have the RE quite right.  Any suggestions? (All sensitive information has been replaced)

```
(more stuff above)
<ns3:insuredInfo>
  <ns3:insuredId>ID12345678</ns3:insuredId>
  <ns3:insuredSecondaryInd>N</ns3:insuredSecondaryInd>
  <ns3:firstName>GEORGE</ns3:firstName>
  <ns3:lastName>WASHINGTON</ns3:lastName>
  <ns3:gender>M</ns3:gender>
</ns3:insuredInfo>
<ns3:patientInfo>
      <ns3:firstName>CATHY</ns3:firstName>
      <ns3:middleInitial>N</ns3:middleInitial>
      <ns3:lastName>LASTLY</ns3:lastName>
      <ns3:gender>F</ns3:gender>
      <ns3:birthDate>08/13/2006</ns3:birthDate>
      <ns3:addressLine1>123 MAIN ST</ns3:addressLine1>
      <ns3:cityName>ANY TOWN</ns3:cityName>
      <ns3:stateName>NY</ns3:stateName>
      <ns3:zipCode>11418</ns3:zipCode>
      <ns3:patientAccountNumber>12345678xyz</ns3:patientAccountNumber>
 </ns3:patientInfo>
   (more stuff underneath)
```

Comment: Are you looking for it to return `ms3` in this case?

Comment: Use `Pattern.MULTILINE`, or `Pattern.DOTALL`

Comment: IMHO, this is a very bad idea, better use an xml parser. If you still want to use a regex, then you can use `(?s)<ns3:patientInfo>.*?<\/ns3:patientInfo>`

Comment: would xml find the tag?  I would want it to return <ns3:patientInfo>